# Notifications of Jenkins Git Changelog

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-sns, slack

I am able to capture the Git change log in Jenkins using the Git Changelog plugin.

Is there any way to trigger notifications of the change log through Slack/Mail/SNS?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [JENKINS Git Changelog Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin) can produce, as a post-buil step, a file, you can use a second Jenkins Job which would monitor such a file (fir instance with the [JENKINS FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin)), and post Slack notification.

See "[Integrating Jenkins with Slack Notifications](https://medium.com/appgambit/integrating-jenkins-with-slack-notifications-4f14d1ce9c7a)", and the [JENKINS Slack Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin) (which is not actively maintained, but is still working for now)